# Slim 4 - Auth Middleware with custom Responce if auth failed

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, jwt, slim

Hope someone can help.
I have a react app using firebase for authentication and firestore database.
I now have the need for a sql database and would like to authorise the requests using the firebase JWT aquired in my react app.

I am using slim 4 and have it to the point where I am sending the JWT from react to Slim, reading it, checking it is a valid token and checking the user is in my sql database.

Where I am struggling is adding middleware that will send a custom responce if the user is not authorised.

Here is the middleware showing my intent if the user is null.

*if the user is null it means either the JWT was invalid or the decoded JWT email and user_id was not in the database.*

```
class AuthMiddleware
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response
    {
        $user = validateFirebaseJWT($request);
        if ($user == null) {
            //throw new HttpForbiddenException($request);
            //throw new HttpUnauthorizedException($request, 'ERROR_401_API_KEY_MISSING');
            $response = new Response();
            $response->getBody()->write('Unauthorised Request');
            return $response->withStatus(403);
        }
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
 }
$app->add(new AuthMiddleware);
```

I have tried several options but all attempts result in an Uncaught Error.

`Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface`

`Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpForbiddenException: Forbidden.`

`Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpUnauthorizedException:`

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you also add a ErrorHandler middleware to catch and transform the Exception?

Comment: I am using this line -> $app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but I recently stumbled myself across this problem and solved with a small workaround.

I also had the problem getting an "`Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface`" error. The reason why you're getting exactly this error message is because PHP doesn't allow to instantiate Interfaces, so another way would be probably instantiating it over a different class, but I'm not sure about it, so I choose a bit different way.

I added the normal `slim/psr7` package with `composer require slim/psr7`.
This gives you the ability to create a new Response inside the function and return it without any errors. So the following code for you would look like this:

```
class AuthMiddleware
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response
    {
        $user = validateFirebaseJWT($request);
        if ($user == null) {
            //throw new HttpForbiddenException($request);
            //throw new HttpUnauthorizedException($request, 'ERROR_401_API_KEY_MISSING');
            $response = new \Slim\Psr7\Response(403);
            $response->getBody()->write('Unauthorised Request');
            return $response;
        }
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}

$app->add(new AuthMiddleware);
```

I hope it might help someone!